# Object of type 'float' / 'int' has no len() error when using nlp() on data

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

Below I applied the nlp() function to one of my columns:

```
import spacy
import pandas as pd
import en_core_web_sm
import numpy
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()

df = pd.read_csv('https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=27211&Year=2019&Month=5&Day=1&timeframe=2&submit=Download+Data')

df['Station Name'] = df['Station Name'].str.title()
col_list = df.columns # obtains the columns of the dataframe

df['Station Name'] = df['Station Name'].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)])

df
```

However when I try to do the same to all of the columns in my data set, I am getting the error `object of type 'int' has no len()` or `object of type 'float' has no len()` Despite trying to ignore those columns with `if df[col].dtype == 'float64' or df[col].dtype == 'float' or df[col].dtype == int or df[col].dtype == 'int64':`

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_data/bulk_data_e.html?format=csv&stationID=27211&Year=2019&Month=5&Day=1&timeframe=2&submit=Download+Data')

df['Station Name'] = df['Station Name'].str.title()
col_list = df.columns # obtains the columns of the dataframe

for col in col_list:
    if df[col].dtype == 'float64' or df[col].dtype == 'float' or df[col].dtype == int or df[col].dtype == 'int64':
        # ignore this column
        continue
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)])
```

I have also tried:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(x).ents)])
```

How can I resolve the issue?

Comment: Perhaps try `df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: [[w.label_] for w in list(nlp(str(x)).ents)])`?

Comment: Seems like it has worked, may I know the logic behind your answer?

Comment: It seems as if some elements must have been ints or floats in those columns. I believe columns that have mixed types return dtype of `object`, so it wouldn't have been filtered out. Here, you ensuring everything is a string.